# Please login as the user "bitnami" rather than the user "root"

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, parse-server, bitnami

[This Is The Image of My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYPAS.png) It want run my android application on parse server using Bitnami . I create EC2 instance with parse but I'm getting error

```
Please login as the user "bitnami" rather than the user "root".
```

While Connecting **.pem** file in terminal and I create Bitnami account and also connect with aws
by using this website https://aws.bitnami.com But still getting that error

Plzz.. Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to ssh into a server as `bitnami` user, here is how your ssh command should look like:

```
ssh -i ./key.pem bitnami@[server-ip-address]
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I have File Name  "sam.pem" first I Use this command "chmod 400 sam.pem"  and then I use this command  "" ssh -i "sam.pem" root@ec2-18-219-19-37.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com ""  still getting error like this

Comment: what I meant was to use the name of the file that has the private key. use `sam.pem` instead of `key.pem`

Comment: do you mean use key.pem only

Comment: its a path. you should enter the path of the file. if the file is in the current directory. you can use `./sam.pem` or you can give a full path of the file.

Comment: It gives error like this    Warning: Identity file key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
root@ec2-18-219-19-37.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: i mean, do not use key.pem. enter your file name, key.pem is an example.

Comment: where do you have the sam.pem located? can you enter the command `pwd` and post it to me. I will adjust the command to access the file from the correct location.

Comment: Now it shows like Please login as the user "bitnami" rather than the user "root"

Comment: You can see the image

Comment: ok, replace `root` with `bitnami`. see if it works. if it doesnt work, send me the screenshot

Comment: But I have no idea how to change root to Bitnami

Comment: I mean in the command, cant you change the word `root` to `bitnami`

Comment: like this =>  `ssh -i sam.pem bitnami@ec2-18-219-19-37.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 2):

Just use "bitnami" instead of "root" in the putty terminal.It worked for me so hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the name "root" in saved session type "bitnami"
                            OR
leave the saved session as empty and click open after that enter "bitnami" in login in command